# sending push notification in php without node.js

Tags: php, push-notification

is it possible to send php push notification without node.js (not installed in my shared web hosting) if I have the client pushSubscription(endpoint, keys) in my database ?
and how if it is ?

Comment: Can you clarify what kind of push notifications? i.e. Web, iOS (APNS) or Android?

Comment: web, i have installed service worker already

Comment: If you use Laravel you can have a look at Laravel Websockets https://beyondco.de/docs/laravel-websockets/getting-started/introduction

Comment: I am afraid this is something bigger than my brain limits, I just needed a code line to send the notification to the endpoint, OR, I thought it was that easy,       but u reminded me of looking for a library to help.. thank you both for your time anyway !

Comment: @KaKe if you're using composer to manage dependencies, (if not please do so) then try searching on packagist.org, there are multiple libraries available with good examples

Comment: Well, u r right, it seems it is the only solution for my case as far as I found out, but dunno how to use composer while i dont have a Terminal window, i dont see solutions other than upgrading to a vps plan so far